# How can I add 1s in a python pandas column like row(n)=row(n-1)+1?

Tags: python, pandas, time, epoch

I need to create a simple python-pandas column looking like this :

```
(1607674395.805080)
(1607674396.805080)
(1607674397.805080)
(1607674398.805080)
(1607674399.805080)
```

Where the first row is (time.time()) (time since epoch) and I would like to add 1s juste like row(n)=row(n-1)+1s until the end of the next column called 'data' for exemple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use shift method:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import time
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.3f' % x)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=np.random.random(5)))
df['new'] = np.arange(df.shape[0]) + time.time() # <<< this is the line that does the magic
df['strs'] = '(' + df['new'].round(6).astype(str) + ')'
>>> df

    a       new             strs
0   0.119   1607948475.922  (1607948475.922189)
1   0.716   1607948476.922  (1607948476.922189)
2   0.561   1607948477.922  (1607948477.922189)
3   0.188   1607948478.922  (1607948478.922189)
4   0.995   1607948479.922  (1607948479.922189)
```

Comment: i made an edit... didnt understand well the question in the first time...

Comment: Great it does the job thanks, even if I don't understand how the magic works :) How can I format the "new" column now to have () like (1607946356.882)

Comment: strings will be fine, this is just because I need to print it that way

Comment: One more question, how can I limit the result to 6 decimal numbers after the '.' ?

Comment: one more question :) if you could show me how to increment each row in the strs column of 1 millisecond instead of 1s... thx !

Comment: instead of writing `np.arange(df.shape[0])` do `(np.arange(df.shape[0]) / 1000)`